# Send push message to users encouraging leaving itunes feedback

Tags: parse-platform

How do you link to your itunes review site in a Parse push message, is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Option 1) First, create a custom activity in your app and all that activity should do is automatically open up the link to the whatever website/iTunes/app store product you want them to review.

Then, you can set your push notification via Parse to open that activity when the user clicks on it.  See the section called "Responding with a Custom Activity" at this link.  https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Option 2) At the same link, see the section for Responding with a Custom URI and simply use the URI to direct them to your website/iTunes/app store/etc.  https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Comment: I see the link is for Android only (?)

Comment: Is this doable without coding knowledge? I notice that Parse allows you to use JSON in push message. Any experience with JSON, can i just add a URL in the push, as easy as that?

Comment: The link is for Android but you can do the same thing for iOS.  No, you can't just add a URL into the JSON data of the push message...you need to do one of the two methods I described above.  Both require coding knowledge - how do you even have an app if you don't have someone who can code?

Comment: Didnt say i didnt have anyone that can code, i said i dont code myself. My coder is not available atm

Comment: If you show your developer those two options above, neither of them are hard - shouldn't take more than a few hours to knock out.

Comment: Im trying to send regular push, but im getting this: "Please select a device type to push to."

Comment: Are you sending the push from the Parse console or via one of the Parse APIs?

Comment: I can't see your screenshot but I assume when you say "I can't see any field for selecting device type" that you mean you are trying to do this through parse's online push console.  You can't do it that way.  You need to do this with actual code. You have to send the push message programmatically, and use one of the two methods I described above to automatically open the link in the app store.  Really, you need your developer to do this, you're just going to continue running in circles trying to do this if you can't code.

Comment: I think you misunderstanding, forget about the link, i just want to send a regular text push, and that should be doable through online console, right? Here is the screenshot again (remove the open slots): http:// prnt.sc/ b5itlq

Comment: If you just want to send a push that says "Please go to the app store and review our app" then just enter that in the box that says "Write Your Message" and leave it as Plain Text.  If you actually want it to automatically send them to the app store when they click on the push, you need to do one of the two methods I described in my original answer.